# How to fix '_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<' ' error in Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

The problem I encountered when I ran the official code of maskrcnn-benchmark for facebookresearch,which was wrong when loading the pre-training model.

The code runs on a remote server at the school and the graphics card is an NVIDIA P100.

checkpointer = DetectronCheckpointer(
        cfg, model, optimizer, scheduler, output_dir, save_to_disk)
extra_checkpoint_data = checkpointer.load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHT)
arguments.update(extra_checkpoint_data)

I expect to run the code correctly and understand why this is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The reason about the problem is that the previous download was not finished. So when I deleted the original file and re-downloaded it, the problem was solved.